# Confused about __import__ in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

friends.a.py how to get b.py module

```
    fileA
    ├── fileB
    │    ├──a.py
    │    └── b.py
    └── fileC
          └── c.py
```

In a.py file, i can use this code to get function from b.py and run it:

```
module = __import__('b')
fun = getattr(module, 'run')
fun()
```

How can I get c.py function in a.py?

Comment: End this question.Do not answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End question.
I have found some one had been ask this same question.
link:[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

His answer:
For Python 3.5+ use:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

For Python 3.3 and 3.4 use:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo = SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/path/to/file.py").load_module()
foo.MyClass()
```

(Although this has been deprecated in Python 3.4.)

Python 2 use:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

There are equivalent convenience functions for compiled Python files and DLLs.

See also. http://bugs.python.org/issue21436.